# How Do I Play Sound from another java activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, audio

As we know the main activity in Android, Eclipse is called MainActivity.java

Actually I have two activites, the second one is: Page2Activity.java

And I have a Page2.xml too for the layout.

I would like to know how can I switch to Page2Activity.java when pushing a button? Because only Page2.xml shows up, and when I click on a button to play a sound nothing happens on the second page.

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
    bpage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    setContentView(R.layout.page2);
                }
            });
...
```

When I push this button, page2.xml shows up, but it contains sound from Page2Activity.java and when I hit a button the sounds won't play. Could you please tell me how can I load Page2Activity.java with layout page 2?

Regards,
Henrik

Comment: Do you want to switch from MainActivity to Page2Activity? Go from the first one to the second one, with their respective xml layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fire an event on click action for the button and start page2 Activity on it's listener.

```
bpage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2Activity.class);
 startActivty(i);

 });
```

Comment: When trying to switch to page 2, I am getting the error: Unfortunately, <appname> has stopped. Btw the code is working I guess.

Logcat is telling me that I need to declare Page2Activity in the manifest. How can I do that?

Comment: Read the stacktrace from logcat and find what crashes your application. Post logcat.

Comment: I have to declare Page2Activity in the manifest.

12-27 22:20:01.131: E/AndroidRuntime(9052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 22:20:01.131: E/AndroidRuntime(9052): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.soundtest/com.example.soundtest.Page2Activity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start the other activity *Page2Activity* when you click on yout *bpage2*-Button?

Put this in your listener instead of *setContentView(R.layout.page2);* :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Calling *setContentView()* sets the layout of your activity - that's why you see the other layout after clicking the button. So what you do is just switching the layout but the logic (e.g. attached listeners) is missing and needs to be implemented. That's why the sound doesn't play. The layout coexists with the logic but it's independant from the logic. Including a xml-layout doesn't mean you include the logic too.
Check out the Fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

In addition take a look on this introduction on how to start an activity from another one: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html .

Maybe you should even start here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html :)

Good luck.

Comment: When trying to switch to page 2, I am getting the error: Unfortunately, <appname> has stopped. Btw the code is working I guess.

Logcat is telling me that I need to declare Page2Activity in the manifest. How can I do that?